# How to create a wiki page for Dashboard In acumatica

Tags: acumatica

How to create a wiki page for Dashboard In Acumatica?
#I want to create a Wiki Page with Image like same to same **CRM Flow**.
But i want to take my own image.
Please mention steps one by one

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can do with a wiki page, here is a link to the central help around Wiki pages in Acumatica:
https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c82c0ace-03e7-421c-9ca5-bc13270f4bb0

Here is another article you may find useful demonstrating creation of a wiki, including uploading images to the wiki:
https://www.greytrix.com/blogs/acumatica/2022/04/28/create-and-update-wiki-article-in-acumatica/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).